# Ask about object definition in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, commonjs

I saw someone define class like

```
define(function (require) {

var Test = {}


Test.init = function() {
}

Test.init();

return Test;
}
```

I am wondering why using define(function (require) ?

Comment: `define` is nothing special. Its a function which takes a function as arguement and that function also have an arguement `require`.

Answer (score 3):

without seeing the rest of the script, I'll have to assume that [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) is being used.

[using `define` provides a convenient mechanism for initializing modules in requirejs.](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#define)

Comment: +1. And as for the `require` argument, see http://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html.

Comment: @ruakh, I have only ever seen `define` used in this manner with requirejs. There are certainly other libraries and frameworks that make use of `define` in different ways. Thanks for the additional information.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your reply. I agree with you that the posted code is using RequireJS. I didn't say anything about there being other libraries that use `define`.

Comment: @ruakh, I misread your comment, I thought you were bringing up the concept of alternative commonjs libraries.

Answer (score 0):

It's a modular approach. You can read about it at [http://addyosmani.com](http://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/)